# LibGDX app renders incorrectly on iOS after device rotation

Tags: ios, libgdx

I have a simple GDX application - completely boilerplate except for the game code:

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    int width = 0, height = 0;
    ShapeRenderer sr;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        super.create();
        sr = new ShapeRenderer();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.6f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        sr.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
        sr.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        sr.rect(width/4f, height/4f, width/2f, height/2f);
        sr.end();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        sr.dispose();
    }
}
```

On Android this works as expected, with the resulting image staying the same when the device is rotated between landscape and portrait.

On iOS the display is correct when the app starts, but if it is then rotated 90 degrees the image is redrawn incorrectly. The image below shows the difference between starting in portrait vs starting in landscape then rotating to portrait.

It appears to me that on iOS in the `render()` function the GDX backend seems to be unaware that the aspect ratio has changed, but I have no idea how to fix that, or why it should work correctly on one platform but not the other.

I have tested with GDX 1.9.5 and 1.10.0 with no difference.

[image: Sample displays]

Answer (score 0):

1. It appears to be a bug.
2. It can be worked around by updating the `resize()` function to:

```
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        super.resize(width, height);
        HdpiUtils.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
```

It seems that the Android backend implicitly resizes the `glViewport` after a screen size change, whereas the iOS backend does not.